# Need help on table design how to consider when an item from table_a is referenced on table_b

Tags: mysql, database-design

i'm out of idea. i first want to inform everyone that i am in no way a DBA. assuming i have table design as below:

```
table_a:
--------------------------------------------------------
- id - ref_no - date_added - added_by - void_record_id -
--------------------------------------------------------
-  1 - dt_001 - 2019-01-01 -        1 -              0 -
-  2 - dt_002 - 2019-01-01 -        1 -              0 -
-  3 - dt_003 - 2019-01-02 -        1 -              0 -
-  4 - dt_004 - 2019-01-02 -        1 -              0 -
-  5 - dt_005 - 2019-01-03 -        2 -              1 -
--------------------------------------------------------

table_b:
------------------------------------------------------------
- id - table_a_id - date_added - added_by - void_record_id -
------------------------------------------------------------
-  1 -          1 - 2019-01-04 -        1 -              0 -
-  2 -          3 - 2019-01-04 -        1 -              0 -
------------------------------------------------------------

void_record:
----------------------------------------------------
- id - void_by - date_added - remarks              -
----------------------------------------------------
-  1 -       3 - 2019-01-05 - removed from records -
----------------------------------------------------
```

think of `table_a` as some sort of a repository for all items added to the database. `table_b` then acts as a log for what items a user took from `table_a`. `void_record` then contains all voiding logs that happened. this is done instead of deleting the row, so i still have a history of what happened to the specific item (was it voided? how many times? by who? and when? etc). if `void_record_id` is set to 0, then it means the data on `table_1` is valid. otherwise, it is invalid or is a "voided record".

now the thing is, a module i'm working on displays all records from table_a `WHERE void_record_id = 0;`. with records `1` and `3` of `table_a` now referenced in `table_b`, how can i cancel them out of `table_a` without voiding them out since they were "took" not "voided". These referenced items should no longer appear on the application since they are already in use.

i am open to the idea of adding columns, or tables. but the former would be better.

sorry about that.

cheers.

Comment: I am having some difficulty understanding the challenge you are working through. To me it would seem that you would be able to have a conditional check in your query.  Run a LEFT JOIN to table_B and display records that either have void_record_id = 0 OR table_b IS NOT NULL (via a 2 part WHERE condition).  Is there a particular reason that solution would not work?  (I may just be mis-understanding your specific application need).

Comment: the purpose of `void_record_id = 0` is to signify that the record is currently active and valid. 1 item can have multiple duplicate records, but we'd only want to consider the latest one. thus considering the records before it voided (void_record_id is set to a value not equal to 0 then).

Comment: normally, if a record from `table_a` is referenced on `table_b`, that does not count as a voided record. so the challenge i am facing is how i can consider "that" unit canceled out of table_a on queries when it is added on `table_b`

Comment: I am still not seeing the nuance of this the same way you are.  Please correct a sort of "story" of my understanding.  I (a user) am on a online store.  Items available for me to buy are on `table_a`.  If `table_a.voided_item_id <> 0` then that item appears on the web page for me to purchase.  After I successfully check out and pay for my item, a record is added onto `table_b`.  The next day that same record from `table_a` is voided (`table_a.voided_item_id <> 0`).  What do I do with the record on `table_b` keeping track that I ordered that same item the previous day?